# write to a JDBC source in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write classic sql query using scala to insert some information into a sql server database table.

The connection to my database works perfectly and I succeed to read data from JDBC, from a table recently created called "textspark" which has only 1 column called "firstname" `create table textspark(firstname varchar(10))`.

However, when I try to write data into the table , I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: textspark
```

this is my code:

```
//Step 1: Check that the JDBC driver is available
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

//Step 2: Create the JDBC URL
val jdbcHostname = "localhost"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase ="mydatabase"
val jdbcUsername = "mylogin"
val jdbcPassword = "mypwd"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

// Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()

connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")

//Step 3: Check connectivity to the SQLServer database
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)



//Read data from JDBC
val textspark_table = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "textspark", connectionProperties)
textspark_table.show()

//the read operation works perfectly!!


//Write data to JDBC
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode


spark.sql("insert into textspark values('test') ")
     .write
     .mode(SaveMode.Append) // <--- Append to the existing table
     .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "textspark", connectionProperties)

//the write operation generates error!!
```

Can anyone help me please to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `insert` statement in `Spark`. You specified the append mode what is ok. You shouldn't insert data, you should select / create it. Try something like this:

```
spark.sql("select 'text'")
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "textspark", connectionProperties)
```

or

```
Seq("test").toDS
  .write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .jdbc(jdbcUrl, "textspark", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: bottaio, If I have a table with several columns, how can I insert into a specific one? For example if the table is created as following: create table textspark(firstname varchar(10), lastname varchar(10)) and I want to insert "James" into firstname column, how can I do that?

Comment: your code : spark.sql("select 'text'").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcUrl, "textspark", connectionProperties) generate the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Column "text" not found in schema Some(StructType(StructField(firstname,StringType,true))); It works only when I put spark.sql("select 'firstname'") which is incoherent (it insert firstname in the column firstname).  So it works only when the string I would insert has the same value as the column name. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @user3569267 `"select 'text' as firstname"` or `Seq("test").toDS("firstName")`